# how to play sound file when application come back in foreground?

Tags: ios, audio, background

I have one sound file which is playing continuosly in application. What I want is when my app goes in background my audio file should pause and when my app comes in foreground my audio file should start playing . What scenario I want is if my audio file is of 4 min and it is playing and at current it is played of 2 min then app goes in background for 1 min then my audio file should now start playing from that 3 min play not from 2 min at which it was paused.
I don't want to use background mode of capabilities. Is there any other way to accomplish this? My code is as below:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],soundFile]];

    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops =-1;
    audioPlayer.volume=0.5f;


    if (audioPlayer == nil)
        NSLog(@"error playing file.");
    else
        [audioPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**

When your application go to background or goes to inactive state, you need to save the current playback time.

You can get the `currentTime` by using [currentTime](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Chapters/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/currentTime) property of `AVAudioPlayer`

You can save the value to [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for persistence

You can use the following delegate to detect the application inactive state

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

**Step 2**

When your come active, you can retrieve the data from the `NSUserDefaults` and using that you can play it from the time where your music stopped.

For detecting the state, you need to use:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

You can set the `currentTime` property for restarting the playing from the position where you stopped it.

Comment: playAtTime method plays sound file in future after specified time but what I want is my audio file now play at skiping background time+already played time.

Answer (score -1):

Take audioPlayer object at global.
when your app goes to background then add below code
In AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
     [audioPlayer pause];
}
```

When your comes in background then add below code in AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
     [audioPlayer play];
}
```

Comment: Please read the requirement carefully, her question is to play the audio skipping the background time.